# Empty response from server running inside Docker container

Tags: java, macos, docker

I have a Docker container running on my laptop containing a server. The server is running at `localhost:9000`. I've set up port-forwarding between my laptop and the VM like this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port9000,tcp,,9000,,9000";
```

Now, I try to start a container like this:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -t -i my-image
```

But when I try to connect, I get the following error:

```
$ curl localhost:9000                                                   
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Looking at the logs of my server, the request never even makes it there, so something else must be wrong. How can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: login inside the docker container and do the curl. First check whether your application is running or not

Comment: I get the expected response when curling from the container.

Comment: could it be that your server binding doesn't accept non-localhost connections? You can check with `docker run --rm -it --link <container id of the running my-image> <image with curl> curl server:9000`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The solution was to use IP address `0.0.0.0`